# how to hide console window to run py file in virtualenv?

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file, virtualenv

`start env\Scripts\activate.bat` shows console window

run.bat:

```
@echo off
cd d:\bal
start env\Scripts\activate.bat
start pythonw  bal.py
exit
```

run.vbs:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell" ) 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "run.bat" & Chr(34), 0 
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Comment: Using a virtual environment doesn't require activating it in a shell. Either run it directly using "pythonw.exe" from the environment's "Scripts" directory, or make it a .pyw GUI script with a fully-qualified shebang, e.g. `#!C:\Path\To\Some\Venv\Scripts\pythonw.exe`. For the latter to work, .pyw files need to be associated with the pyw.exe launcher.

Comment: Sloved, thanks!  The .vbs file  is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

Save the file as .pyw

Hope this helps :)